# how to make a normal zip file for users in a web application using C#?

Tags: c#, web-applications, outputstream, dotnetzip, sharpcompress

I have the following code to create a downloadable zip archive that works fine:

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
zip.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.Always;
zip.AddFiles(filePaths, false, ".");
string zipName = String.Format("Files_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd"));
Response.Clear();
Response.BufferOutput = false;
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```

users usually open files within a zip archive without extracting that. unfortunately I cannot open a file without extracting when using above code to create a zip archive. when trying to open a file an extra window appears shown as below:
[image]

I tried both two namespaces: Ionic.Zip and SharpCompress and the problem appears in either one.
any help would be appreciated. tks

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct but keep in mind that [XLSX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) file format is a zip file.

What happened, is that WinRAR treats it as an archive and just unpacks it.

You can configure WinRAR and tell it to open `xlxs` files using Excel.

Go to 
**Options** -> **Settings** -> **Viewer** and select Excel as an **Associated Program** for `*.xlsx`
http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/html/helpviewersettings.htm

Comment: thank you for your comment, please note that we do not have access to the clients! users open the provided zip files on their own way. besides, users can open the .Xlsx, docx and other formats directly when the files are zipped using Winrar, Winzip etc. therefore, the problem is not about the Associated program!

Comment: In fact I do not know what the differences between these zip files are. the differences that Winrar treats *.docx, *.XSLX and other microsoft office files as zip file when using above code while it opens directly when already using winrar to compress them.